# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the Lie group embedding $G \supset J$ can be lifted to $G$'s covering space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, lie-groups, embeddings

Suppose the Lie group $G$ contains the Lie group $J$ as a subgroup, so
$$
G \supset J.
$$

If $G$ has a nontrivial first homotopy group $\pi_1(G) \neq 0$.

If $G$ has a universal cover $\widetilde{G}$, so $\pi_1(\widetilde{G}) = 0$.

> Question: What are the necessary and sufficient conditions to derive that
> $$
> \widetilde{G} \supset J \quad (?)
> $$
> is also true via a lifting?
> $$
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>   &  & \widetilde{G}\\
>           &\nearrow &           \downarrow\\
>  J & \longrightarrow & G
> \end{array}.
> $$

My thought:

1. Sufficient condition may be $\pi_1(J)=0$, due to the property $\pi_1(\widetilde{G})=0$.
2. Necessary condition may be that
   $\pi_1(J) \to \pi_1({G})$ is a trivial group homomorphism, which maps all $\pi_1(J)$ to 0,
   because this map
   can be decomposed by $\pi_1(J) \to \pi_1(\widetilde{G})=0$ and $\pi_1(\widetilde{G})=0 \to \pi_1({G})$.
3. The above conditions are for universal covering $\widetilde{G}$, what would be the conditions for the (non-universal) covering space $\widetilde{G}$?

Comment: You don't seem to want a covering group. That would make the question more interesting.

Comment: Please give advice what would be more interesting, please?

Comment: please comment @Fernando Muro - I can improve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lifting to covers is completely understood; the necessary and sufficient requirement is that the image of the fundamental group lies in the subgroup associated to the cover. So, for example, you are correct that to lift to the universal cover the map on fundamental groups must be trivial. For a reference, see chapter 1 of Hatcher proposition 1.33.

Comment: many thanks for this - +1 - can you also comment on (a) the proof, (b) the case that it is not universal cover but just a covering space?

Comment: The proof is written in Hatcher, it is the precursor to obstruction theory basically. I am not exactly sure what you want regarding (b). The associated subgroup i mention is the image of the fundamental group of the total space, so if you have a cover you should compute the image of its fundamental group and then check if loops in your sub-Lie group all lie in this subgroup of the fundamental group.

Comment: many thanks again

Comment: Would your necessary and sufficient requirement compatible with the case $J=U(1)$, $\widetilde{G}=SU(2)$ and $G=SO(3)$ still can have the lift such that $⊃$ but also $\widetilde{G}⊃$?

Comment: I do not know what your maps are so I can't say.